# Hi I am getting the error in anypoint studio version 6.4.2

Tags: anypoint-studio, openjdk-11

> Errors occurred during the build.
> Errors running builder 'Mule Builder' on project 'flex-data-mapper'.
> javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

The java version i am using is java 11

and the AnypointStudio.ini file is

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-vmargs
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/AnypointStudio/workspace
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Current version of Anypoint Studio (6.6.5 and 7.6.0 at this time) [do not support Java 11 to start the IDE](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/studio/anypoint-studio-7.6-with-4.3-runtime-release-notes#software-requirements). You should use AdoptOpenJDK 8, though another Java/OpenJDK 8 will probably work as well. After it starts you can [configure Java 11 to run a Mule 4.2.0 or later version projects](https://docs.mulesoft.com/studio/7.6/change-jdk-config-in-projects). Earlier versions of Mule don't support Java 11. That means that any project in Studio 6.x is not compatible with Java 11 either, because it only runs Mule 3.x applications.

As a sidenote, if you are still using Mule 3.x, then I recommend to download Studio 6.6.5 as a new install, because of the number of fixes since Studio 6.4.2. It can't be upgraded inside Studio.